# How to print pandas dataframe containing some russian language

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ipython

I am working on a following type of data.

```
      itemid      category             subcategory               title
    1 10000010   Транспорт     Автомобили с пробегом     Toyota Sera, 1991
    2 10000025      Услуги         Предложения услуг         Монтаж кровли
    3 10000094 Личные вещи Одежда, обувь, аксессуары      Костюм Steilmann
    4 10000101   Транспорт     Автомобили с пробегом      Ford Focus, 2011
    5 10000132   Транспорт     Запчасти и аксессуары       Турбина 3.0 Bar
    6 10000152   Транспорт     Автомобили с пробегом ВАЗ 2115 Samara, 2005
```

Now I run the following commands

```
    import pandas as pd
    trainingData = pd.read_table("train.tsv",nrows=10, header=0,encoding='utf-8')


    trainingData['itemid'].head()
    0    10000010
    1    10000025
    2    10000094
    3    10000101
    4    10000132
    Name: itemid
```

Everything is good this point but when I do something like

```
trainingData['itemid','category'].head()

    Error:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    /home/vikram/Documents/Avito/ in ()
    ----> 1 trainingData[['itemid','category']].head()

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
        236             self.start_displayhook()
        237             self.write_output_prompt()
    --> 238             format_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
        239             self.write_format_data(format_dict)
        240             self.update_user_ns(result)

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in compute_format_data(self, result)
        148             MIME type representation of the object.
        149         """
    --> 150         return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
        151 
        152     def write_format_data(self, format_dict):

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in format(self, obj, include, exclude)
        124                     continue
        125             try:
    --> 126                 data = formatter(obj)
        127             except:
        128                 # FIXME: log the exception


    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
        445                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
        446                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
    --> 447             printer.pretty(obj)
        448             printer.flush()
        449             return stream.getvalue()

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
        352                 if callable(obj_class._repr_pretty_):
        353                     return obj_class._repr_pretty_(obj, self, cycle)
    --> 354             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
        355         finally:
        356             self.end_group()

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
        472     if getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
        473         # A user-provided repr.

    --> 474         p.text(repr(obj))
        475         return
        476     p.begin_group(1, ' 456                 self.to_string(buf=buf)
        457                 value = buf.getvalue()
        458                 if max([len(l) for l in value.split('\n')]) > terminal_width:

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.pyc in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, colSpace, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, nanRep, index_names, justify, force_unicode)
       1024                                            index_names=index_names,
       1025                                            header=header, index=index)
    -> 1026         formatter.to_string(force_unicode=force_unicode)
       1027 
       1028         if buf is None:

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/format.pyc in to_string(self, force_unicode)
        176             for i, c in enumerate(self.columns):
        177                 if self.header:
    --> 178                     fmt_values = self._format_col(c)
        179                     cheader = str_columns[i]
        180                     max_len = max(max(len(x) for x in fmt_values),

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/format.pyc in _format_col(self, col)
        217                             float_format=self.float_format,
        218                             na_rep=self.na_rep,
    --> 219                             space=self.col_space)
        220 
        221     def to_html(self):

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/format.pyc in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify)
        424                         justify=justify)
        425 
    --> 426     return fmt_obj.get_result()
        427 
        428 

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/format.pyc in get_result(self)
        471                 fmt_values.append(float_format(v))
        472             else:
    --> 473                 fmt_values.append(' %s' % _format(v))
        474 
        475         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/format.pyc in _format(x)
        457             else:
        458                 # object dtype

    --> 459                 return '%s' % formatter(x)
        460 
        461         vals = self.values

    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/common.pyc in _stringify(col)
        503 def _stringify(col):
        504     # unicode workaround

    --> 505     return unicode(col)
        506 
        507 def _maybe_make_list(obj):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

please help me "display" the data properly.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue caused by IPython, which could not display non-ASCII text returned by the Pandas `head()` function. It turned out that the default encoding for Python was set to `'ascii'` on my machine. You can check this with

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

The solution was to re-set the default encoding to UTF-8:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

After this, IPython displayed Pandas data frames with non-ASCII characters correctly.

*Note that the `reload` call is necessary to make the `setdefaultencoding` function available. Without it you'll get the error:*

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```