# Python pandas filter by word

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, contains

I have
csv file:

```
df=pd.read_csv(Path(os.getcwd()+r'\all_files.csv'), sep=',', on_bad_lines='skip', index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
```

column:

```
column=input("Column:")
```

word:

```
word=input("Word:")
```

I want to filter a csv file:

```
df2=df[(df[column].dropna().str.contains(word.lower()))]
```

But when I  write to column:ЄДРПОУ(Гр.8)

I have a error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\python\python\FilterExcelFiles.py", line 35
    df2=df[(df[column].dropna().str.contains(word.lower()))]
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\python\FilterExcelFiles.py", line 51, in <module>
    s()
  File "C:\python\python\FilterExcelFiles.py", line 35, in s
    df2=df[(df[column].dropna().str.contains(word.lower()))]
  File "C:\Users\Станислав\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3496, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
  File "C:\Users\Станислав\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3549, in _getitem_bool_array
    key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
  File "C:\Users\Станислав\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2383, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError(
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

And I wont to lower df[column]

Answer (score 2):

You're dropping the NaN in the indexer, making it likely shorter, which results in the error in boolean indexing.

Don't dropna, the NaN will be False anyway:

```
df2 = df[df[column].str.contains(word.lower())]
```

Alternatively, if you had a operation that would return NaNs, you could fill them with `False`:

```
df2 = df[df[column].str.contains(word.lower()).fillna(False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched around for an answer and I came across [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894213/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-containing-some-russian-language) that might have the solution for your problem.

According to the mentioned post, the reason for this error is due to the encoding for Python, which is usually `ascii`; the encoding can be checked by:

```py
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

To solve your problem, you need to change it to `UTF-8`, using the following!

```py
import sys
reload(sys)   # Note this line is essential for the change 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Would like to credit the original solution to [@jochietoch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4542909/jochietoch)